# Read in only certain rows

Tags: r

I have the set of data below. It has a few rows of unwanted characters before the numbers I want to read in, as well as a few unwanted rows after the data. I created a substring that will serve as my first column, which is purely numerical. There is data, when the set is read in, above and below these numericals that were converted to NA. Is there a way, other than skip and nrow, that I can remove the NA rows and read in only those rows that are numerical?

```
x<-read.csv("..."),
   header=FALSE, na.strings="Y") 
y<-substr(x$V1,1,8)
y<-as.numeric(y)

x2<-cbind(y,x1)
x2<-as.data.frame(x2)
```

I have tried:

```
if (x$y == is.numeric) {
    print(x)
} else {
    print("")}
```

But that is clearly wrong as all I get are errors. I have been trying different combinations of the above code, as well as:

```
x3<-sapply(x$y,is.numeric)
x[x3,]
```

But nothing I try is working.. I am either completely off or am missing something.

UPDATE: I was able to do this with both methods that were answered below.. but the problem now is, since the rows above the numeric rows contained characters, my columns are factors rather than numeric. Rather than actually deleting the rows, we were just temporarily removing them. Is there a way to permanently remove them so that my columns will be class numeric?

Comment: Have you tried the `skip` and `nrow` arguments in `read.csv()`?

Comment: Whoops, I said nobs= up top. I meant to say skip and nrow. I am going to apply this code to multiple datasets with differing row numbers, so skip and nrow will not work when applied to the different sets.

Comment: It would be nice to have an example of the file and how you wish to read it into R.  Would `na.omit(x)` work?

Answer (score 1):

If this is just the case of remove rows containing NAs, have you tried using [`complete.cases`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/complete.cases.html)? Perhaps something like:

```
x2[complete.cases(x2),]
```

Also if would be great if you could provide a minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: Both methods do work but I forgot that I also have NAs within the data set, so I must convert only those certain column NAs to 0 before using either of those two. Thanks!